# PHP, Inserting into Table - No Database selected?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to query a table and then depending on an if statement insert information into that table.

I have the following so far but I keep receiving the error

```
"No database selected"
```

**DBConfig.php**

```
$username = 'access@new';
$password = 'access';

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=new_site_co_uk', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Query page**

```
function checkUser($uid, $oauth_provider, $username,$email,$twitter_otoken,$twitter_otoken_secret) 
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE oauth_uid = '$uid' and oauth_provider = '$oauth_provider'") or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if (!empty($result)) {
        # User is already present
    } else {
        #user not present. Insert a new Record
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username,email,twitter_oauth_token,twitter_oauth_token_secret) VALUES ('$oauth_provider', $uid, '$username','$email','','')") or die(mysql_error());
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE oauth_uid = '$uid' and oauth_provider = '$oauth_provider'");
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        return $result;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**PDO**

```
    $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_uid = :uid AND oauth_provider = :oauth_provider');
    $sth->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
    $sth->bindParam(':oauth_provider', $oauth_provider);
    $sth->execute();
```

Comment: PDO or mysql, which is it?!

Answer (score 2):

If you use PDO to connect to the database, you have to use PDO to send queries to the database. You cannot use the mysql extension to send queries in that case.

Use [`PDO::query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) to send `SELECT` queries and [`PDO::exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) for other queries. You might also want to consider [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).